# Ubuntu User WWW/FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, apache-2.2

I have a user named 'user' which I use to login to the ftp of my website.

However, this presents me with a problem.

If I want to allow my user to access to ftp, I have to typ the following:

```
chown -R user:ftpusers /var/www/
```

By doing this, my website is no longer available when surfing to it. To make it available again, I have to typ the following command:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
```

the user 'user' is in both the ftpusers and www-data group. How can I fix this so I wouldn't have to typ this anymore?

I'm using apache2 and vsftpd on ubuntu

Comment: `chown www-data:ftpusers`, perhaps?

Comment: By doing that, the website works, but the ftp fails

Comment: SnIpY: You may need `chmod g+w` to add group write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To best share with multiple users who should be able to write in `/var/www`, it should be assigned a common group. For example the default group for web content on Ubuntu and Debian is `www-data`. Make sure all the users who need write access to `/var/www` are in this group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data <some_user>
```

Then set the correct permissions on /var/www.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

Additionally, you should make the directory and all directories below it "set GID", so that all *new* files and directories created under `/var/www` are owned by the `www-data` group.

```
sudo find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
```

Find all files in `/var/www` and add read and write permission for owner and group:

```
sudo find /var/www -type f -exec chmod ug+rw {} \;
```